# Alert not showing up herewindow.addEventListener('resize',

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

My window `.resize` function is not working.
When I reduce the browser window I am trying to reduce the cube size to fit the iPhone layout.
The problem is its not changing and even I don't see the alert.
The problem is in this line line no 354.

Providing my code below:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
        if (screen.width < 900) {
            alert("i am here");
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using jQuery, so you can try this approach:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
     if($(this).width() < 900) {
         alert("i am here");
     }
});
```

Comment: V: thanks for your reply...i updated in the fiddle but its not working http://jsfiddle.net/YZYp5/16/embedded/result/

Comment: By looking at the fiddle you've provided, I see your code is wrong. You wrote `window.addEventListener('resize', function(){ if (($(this).width < 900) { alert("i am here"); }` which is very different from my answer.

Comment: when i change as per your code i cant see nothing http://jsfiddle.net/YZYp5/21/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onresize = function(){
   if(window.innerWidth < 900) {
      alert('hope this help');
   }
}
```

hope this help
jquery is a better approach too

Comment: this works fine...but i f i change cube size inside this function its not working what is the reason window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
        if (window.innerWidth < 900) {
   //alert("i am here");

            Gallery = {
                _config: {
                    speed: 500,
                    size: 25,
                    lightbox: !0,
                    closeOnEsc: !0,
                    animation: "default",
                    slideshow: !1,
                    slideshow_speed: 3E3,
                    cube_speed: 1E3
                },